# Scheduling Auctions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on an auctions site and I want to schedule auction so users can set the date and time they want their auction to start and end. I added Published_at, end_time and draft which is default to true in my db migration and I can create an auction and select a published_at time and end_time which stores in db but I am having difficulty making the auction to now show on the date and time selected and end on the date and time selected.

Model/auction.rb

```
class Auction < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy

  scope :draft, -> {
    where(:draft => true)
  }

  # scope :draft, where(:draft => true)
  scope :published, proc {
    where(:draft => false).where('published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now)
  }


  before_save :ensure_published_at, :unless => :draft?
  protected
  def ensure_published_at
    # Set it to current time if none has been specified.
    self.published_at ||= Time.zone.now
  end

  def publish!
    self.draft = false
    self.save!
  end
end
```

auctions_controller.rb

```
def index
  @auctions = Auction.published
end
```

so I guess what I am trying to do in the model is for the draft to change from true to false so I can show in Index controller, but seems I'm getting many things wrong.

I would appericiate any help please.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having/

Comment: I want the draft to change from true to false but it is not changing, I guess the problem is from my model

Comment: Have you called `@auction.publish!`? If you do that, the action you've published should appear in your published scope and not your draft scope

Comment: @mark Do you mean I should call `<% @auctions.published.each do |auction| %>` in my view? or where should I call the @auction.publish!

Comment: Wherever you intend to publish the auction :) How are you triggering it in your app? I'm guessing there will be some controller you use when you try to publish the auction?

Comment: Basically whichever controller action you're going through (you'll see it in your server logs), you need to add the `@action.publish!` line to - that bit of code will never execute and make an auction published unless you manually call it or trigger it in a controller